# Syntax error, found .and. and .or.

Tags: fortran

I just wanted to modify a small part of a very old program and I can't for the life of me figure out what I've done to anger the Fortran gods.

The original code has the following line:

```
  if (r.gt.rstep) xappad = xappad*fakm
```

which I have modified to:

```
  if (r.gt.0.58*rstep .and. r.lt.1.42*rstep) .or. (r.gt.2.08*rstep 
 : .and. r.lt.2.92*rstep) xappad = xappad*fakm
```

Which gives me the errors:

> sp-co-2-MODIFIED.for(785): error #5082: Syntax error, found '.OR.'
>   when expecting one of: BLOCK BLOCKDATA PROGRAM MODULE TYPE COMPLEX
>   BYTE CHARACTER DOUBLE DOUBLECOMPLEX ...

```
      if (r.gt.0.58*rstep .and. r.lt.1.42*rstep) .or. (r.gt.2.08*rstep 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

sp-co-2-MODIFIED.for(786): error #6090: An array-valued operand is required in this context.

```
     : .and. r.lt.2.92*rstep) xappad = xappad*fakm
------^
```

> sp-co-2-MODIFIED.for(786): error #6087: An array assignment statement
>   is required in this context.

```
     : .and. r.lt.2.92*rstep) xappad = xappad*fakm
-------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: I haven't coded in FORTRAN for almost 25 years, but if I recall it correctly, you need a pair of parentheses around the entire conditional expression.

Answer (score 15):

I really don't know much FORTRAN, but it looks to me like you're missing a pair of parentheses around the conditional:

```
if ((r.gt.0.58*rstep .and. r.lt.1.42*rstep) .or. (r.gt.2.08*rstep .and. r.lt.2.92*rstep)) xappad = xappad*fakm
```

Comment: AH, I knew I was being a massive idiot. That seems to have done it, thank you.